# in ActiveMQ, message is received by Consumer but the Acknowledgment is sent by other process?

Tags: activemq-classic, consumer

In ActiveMQ, I was sending a message to a consumer, the consumer then forwards the message to a different process. I wanted to know  if there is any way by which the acknowledgment can be send to the broker from the other process??

I tried sending the Message Object using a socket connection to the other process and then calling the acknowledge() method on it, it is not working.

I tried the sending the message to some other class object(in the same JAVA process) and then calling the acknowledge() method, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how you are sending the message to the other process...I'd just call acknowledge() in first consumer after the call to deliver it to the other process...that should guarantee that its been delivered (assuming your delivery to the second process is sound)...